# How to findout Non working hours between days in sql server (Previous day end time and next date start time diff for all days in a month)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2012

How to findout Non working hours between days in sql server (Previous day end time and next date start time diff for all days in a month)?
my table structre example

```
StartDT                        EndDT            NonworkingHr's

2012-03-05 09:00:00 2012-03-05 15:00:00      
2012-03-04 10:00:00 2012-03-04 16:00:00         18
2012-03-05 11:00:00 2012-03-05 17:00:00         18
2012-03-06 10:00:00 2012-03-06 15:00:00         15
2012-03-09 16:00:00 2012-03-09 18:00:00         25        
2012-03-10 16:00:00 2012-03-10 19:00:00         26
2012-03-12 16:00:00 2012-03-12 22:00:00         27
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag` to get the previous row's enddt and subtract it from the current row's startdt using `datediff`.

```
select startdt,enddt,
datediff(minute,lag(enddt) over(order by startdt),startdt)/60.0 as non_working_hours
from tablename
```